# Manifolds and Schemes from Idempotent Splitting

Tags: geometry, category-theory, manifolds, smooth-manifolds, schemes

Recently I read on the [nlab](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Karoubi+envelope), that the category $\mathsf{SmoothMf}$ of smooth manifolds can be realized as the Karoubi-envelope / Cauchy-completion of the category $\mathsf{SmoothOpen}$ of open subsets of euclidean spaces $\mathbb R^n$ and smooth maps between them. The proof invokes the [tubular neighborhood theorem](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/tubular+neighborhood+theorem), which (according to a rather coarse search of the internet) seems to be a special property of $\mathsf{SmoothMf}$.

> Regardless I am wondering, whether we can identify the category of topological manifolds $\mathsf{TopMf}$ with the Cauchy-completion of $\mathsf{TopOpen}$, using continuous maps instead of smooth ones.

> Similarly, is the (or some nice subcategory, say smooth ones) category of schemes $\mathsf{Sch}$ realizable as the Cauchy-completion of the category $\mathsf{Aff} = \mathsf{CRing}^{op}$ of affine schemes?

I feel like this question is natural to ask, so it should be answered already, but didn't find any positive nor negative results. Unfortunately I don't really know enough about the differences between $\mathsf{SmoothMf}$ and $\mathsf{TopMf}$ nor do I know much about Cauchy-completions. So I apologize, if there are more than obvious obstructions I just didn't notice yet. Anyway, thank you for your time.

Comment: The category of commutative rings is Cauchy complete, so the category of affine schemes is its own Cauchy completion.

Comment: A pity. I think it would have been a nice way to unify geometry (other than locally ringed spaces or sheaves on a site) ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: I just noted that taking $\mathsf{Aff}$ doesn't really make sense, I guess one should rather use the category of subschemes of affine schemes. So the question remains open...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Regardless I am wondering, whether we can identify the category of topological manifolds TopMf with the Cauchy-completion of TopOpen, using continuous maps instead of smooth ones.

No.  The Cauchy completion of open subsets of $\def\R{{\bf R}} \R^n$ with continuous maps (instead of smooth) is much bigger than the category of topological manifolds.

For example, it contains the gluing of three copies of $[0,∞)$ along $\{0\}$.
It is easy to construct it as a retract of $\R^2$, using a continuous map that (say) projects in the direction of a fixed ray in each of the three regions of $\R^2$.  This map is not smooth.

The reason this does not work in the smooth category is that the retraction must be differentiable at the point $0$, so the derivative must have rank at least 2, which means the retract cannot be 1-dimensional.

Comment: Thank you. This is a nice answer!